# AssemblyBinding BindingRedirect does not work for behaviours configured in the serviceModel. (Wcf)

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

We have a lot of web applications, configured using custom sections (in their `web.config`) that depend on `sectionHandlers` declared in the `machine.config`.

As we have several versions of these `sectionHandlers`, applications that want to use a new `sectionHandlers` have to force "assembly redirection" by using the tag `<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">` in their `web.config`. We can indeed not modify the declaration of the `sectionHandlers` in the `machine.config` as long as there are still other applications using the oldest version.

The binding redirection works fine for all the assemblies loaded by the applications using the tag mentioned before - except for the assemblies containing types used to define a WCF behavior in the web.config's `system.serviceModel` section.

For example, some of our applications are using a custom behavior Extension named `mainframeFormatter` (See in the web.config in the example here after). When adding a `bindingRedirect` from a version 1.1.0.0 of the assembly containing the type `mainframeFormatter` to a version 1.2.0.0, we get the following error:

> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for
>   system.serviceModel/behaviors: Extension element'mainframeFormatter'
>   cannot be added to this element.  Verify that the extension is
>   registered in the extension collection at
>   system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions.

Notice that we only have the problem with the "behaviors" and not with the "bindings".
Is this the expected behavior of the Binding Redirection with WCF behaviors or is this a bug ?

Here's a sample of `web.config` which fails to be parsed when using binding redirection:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name="mainframeFormatter"
              type="Framework.Communication.Mainframe.ClientEndpointBehaviorExtensionElement,
                       Framework.Communication.Mainframe, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                       PublicKeyToken=f510307097254a31"/>
    </behaviorExtensions>
    <bindingExtensions>
      <add name="mainframeBinding" 
              type="Framework.Communication.Mainframe.BindingCollectionElement,
                       Framework.Communication.Mainframe, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                       PublicKeyToken=f510307097254a31"/>
    </bindingExtensions>
  </extensions>

  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ClientEndpointBehavior">
        <mainframeFormatter />  <--- Problem is on parsing this with assemblyBinding enabled
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <bindings>
    <mainframeBinding>
      <binding name="MyCustomBinding"/>
    </mainframeBinding>
  </bindings>

</system.serviceModel>

<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Framework.Communication.Mainframe"
                               publicKeyToken="f510307097254a31" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.2.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

I know that changing the version in the `behaviorExtension` settings solves the problem. But I am curious why the redirection does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will provide a hotfix soon.